# Implementation of Hybrid flow for Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, openid, thinktecture, identityserver3

I need some implementation guidance, I have an AngularJS client with ASP.NET Web API on the server-side. Here are some questions:
1. I have implemented Implicit flow where I'm able to get the id_token and access_token from the IdentityServer. I would like to know if we can implement Hybrid flow that allows refresh-tokens?
2) What's the right way to handle session management on a JavaScript client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit flow dows not support refresh tokens. Authorization Flow does, but should not be used on Javascript clients in websites. This can be used for native apps on mobile devices.

[Here is an article on why you shouldn't use Implicit Flow on mobile devices.](https://medium.com/@justinsecurity/mobile-apps-and-oauths-implicit-flow-68e72c6515a1)